# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat 7.0.82 and JDK-"1.7.0_80". When I copy a jar com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar into tomcat/lib directory I am getting the error. Do you know the reason for this error?

```
SEVERE: Exception initializing page context
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.<init>(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:46)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getInstance(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:76)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl._initialize(PageContextImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:111)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:64)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
```

Comment: Did you add the jar in project build path?

Comment: Tomcat already having el-api.jar. Also if this jar -"com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar " contains the same method in same class. Then there might be error. Multiple instances available in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

The method [javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#newInstance()) was added in the 2.2 version of the expression language api library.

You have to check that the version deployed in the tomcat/lib has the el-api.jar for the version 2.2 and also check if you are not using a different version of the jar in you project in the WEB-INF/lib folder